# My select query returns same data for 3 rows

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am getting the same value for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd. Then the next line gives me the results supposed to be in the 2nd column supposed in the first row.

```
<?php  
 require "db.php"; 
 $sql = "
SELECT e_name
     , IF(t_rank = 1, a_shortcut, a_shortcut) AS 1st
     , IF(t_rank = 1, a_shortcut, a_shortcut) AS 2nd
     , IF(t_rank = 3, a_shortcut, a_shortcut) AS 3rd    
  FROM team t
  JOIN event e
    ON t.EID = e.EID
";                         

 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("e_name"=>$row[0],"1st"=>$row[1], 
"2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[3]));

} 
echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));



mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

My expected output is

Example. `Shortcut has a, b, c and they have rank a =1 b =2 c =3;`

Then `1st = a, 2nd = b, 3rd = c;`

What im getting is

```
1st = a, 2nd = a, 3rd = a;
```

then the next line shows

```
1st = b, 2nd = b, 3rd = b;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "select e_name
 , IF(t_rank = 1,'A',NULL) AS 1st
 , IF(t_rank = 2,'B',NULL) AS 2nd
 , IF(t_rank = 3,'C',NULL) as 3rd    
 from team t
join event e on t.EID = e.EID";
```

this will return rank in A,B,C format..when condition match then it will convert to A,B,C format

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your query as below:

$sql = "select e_name, CASE t_rank when t_rank = 1 then a_shortcut when t_rank = 2 then b_shortcut when t_rank = 3 then c_shortcut END as rank from team inner join event on team.EID = event.EID";

Then use rank field. 
end as matching_tag  from team inner join event on team.EID = event.EID";

Comment: Ask yourself this, does `if(some_condition, col, col)` make any sense?

Comment: there is no condition apply in if ...as true return as well as return false

Comment: No it doesn't mean anything